# manipulate payload on ember data normalizePayload

Tags: date, ember.js, ember-data

How can I manipulate one of the values in `normalizePayload` (I need it anyway to convert result to session)
I need start_time and end_time to be multipled with 1000 in order to get smoothly into an `attr('date')`

```
  "result": [
    {
      "end_time": 1412687629.42063, 
      "start_time": 1412687629.26851, 
    }, 
   {
      "end_time": 1412688377.15329, 
      "start_time": 1412688377.11507, 
    }, 
...
```

The current code I have is:

```
App.SessionSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
        return {
            sessions: payload.result
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I gave you bad info in the answer in your other question.  The `normalizePayload` method should manipulate the `payload` hash directly:

```
App.SessionSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
        payload.sessions= payload.result;
        delete payload.result;
        delete payload.metadata;
        return payload;
    }  
});
```

Comment: well... actually your previous answer did work. but how do I multiply one of the time values by 1000?

Comment: That sort of thing is probably best done with a computed property, but if you want to do it in the `normalizePayload` method, you can do so there.

Comment: How do I access a single field inside normalizePayload? I need to iterate? (doesn't seem right...). Where do I put the computed field. inside DS.Model.extend?

Comment: Yep, the payload is the complete object, so if you want to access items in an array, you'll need to iterate.  Computed properties can be in a model or in a controller.